# Java. Как обозначить аннотацией, что дата не раньше определённой?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, localdate

У меня есть класс Film, у которого поле типа LocalDate должно быть не раньше 28 декабря 1895 года. Я использую следующую библиотеку javax.validation.constraints, где представлены @Past, @Future, @FutureOrPresent, @PastOrPresent. Возможно проблема решается созданием собственной аннотации? Подскажите пожалуйся, где об этом почитать.

```java
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

import javax.validation.constraints.*;

import java.time.LocalDate;

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"id"})
public class Film {
    private int id = 0;
    @NotBlank
    private final String name;
    @Size(max=200)
    private final String description;
    @Future
    private final LocalDate releaseDate;
    @Positive
    private final int duration;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для таких целей придется создать свою кастомную аннотацию и валидатор. Пример [статьи](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation-method-constraints)  на эту тему

Класс аннотации

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = MinimumDateValidator.class)
@Past
public @interface MinimumDate {
    String message() default "Date must not be before {value}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<?>[] payload() default {};

    String value() default "1895-12-28";
}
```

Кастомный класс валидатора, который будет эту аннотацию обрабатывать

```java
public class MinimumDateValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MinimumDate, LocalDate> {
    private LocalDate minimumDate;

    @Override
    public void initialize(MinimumDate constraintAnnotation) {
        minimumDate = LocalDate.parse(constraintAnnotation.value());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(LocalDate value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return value == null || !value.isBefore(minimumDate);
    }
}
```

Пример использования

```java
public class Person {
    @MinimumDate
    private LocalDate birthDate;
}
```